# How to save attribute value on xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to save a value in my xml file. In the code below, the line "s.Attribute("Value").Value = value; break;" executes and the file is saved but it doesn't change the value of the attribute

[image]

```
     public void CustomSettingXML_WriteValue(string key, string value)
    {

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);

        var elements = from x in XElement.Load(xmlFile).Elements("Item") select x;

        foreach (var s in elements)
        {
            if (s.Attribute("Text").Value == key)
            {
                s.Attribute("Value").Value = value; 
                doc.Save(@xmlFile);                    
               break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're loading the xmlfile into `doc` but then you load it separately into `elements`, alter `elements` and then save `doc`. You need to pick one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are in fact two things that might have to vary.

a) You are reading the Xml using XDocument.Load as well as XElement.Load. While altering, you are using Elements, and while saving you are using XDocument.

b) Since hierarchy in XML is (Items.Item), it would be better you use Descendants to parse the elements.

Full Code

```
public void CustomSettingXML_WriteValue(string key, string value)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
    var elements = from x in doc.Descendants("Item") select x;
    foreach (var s in elements)
    {

        if (s.Attribute("Text").Value == key)
        {
            s.Attribute("Value").Value = value; 
            doc.Save(@xmlFile);                    
           break;
        }
    }
}
```